# Use External CSS instead of inline CSS for blockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using blockUI in multiple places and they all have the same properties so i keep on repeating the same css values in all the place I use. is there a way to put it into a CSS file.

currently i use:

```
$.blockUI({
        message: $('#Something'),
        css: {
            border: '5px solid #F4712',
            backgroundColor: '#6F4712',
            width: '300px'
        }
    });
```

can i use like:

```
$.blockUI({
    message: $('#Something'),
        css: {
            class:"alertBox"
        }
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#options) - you can't.

but you to do that :

```
the class $(".blockPage").addClass("myClass")
```

p.s. be sure not to give any styles in the code as you wrote .

and update to something like this :

```
  $.blockUI({ 
            fadeIn: 1000, 
            timeout:   2000, 
            onBlock: function() { 
               $(".blockPage").addClass("myClass");

            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

I was half way through modifying my copy of the blockUI plugin to add this functionality and found there was already a config option for `blockMsgClass`, setting this to your css class adds your class to the block.

```js
$.blockUI(
{
    blockMsgClass: 'alertBox',
    message: 'Hello styled popup'
});
```

One thing to note though is that the plugin code uses inline css so you need to mark as !important for fields such as text-align, color, border, background-color and cursor: wait.

```
.alertBox
{
    border:none !important;
    background-color: #437DD4 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    cursor: default !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic class adding the first answer worked, but some flicker occured, because the class was added too late.
So I added my custom class before the blockUI to the body and changed my css a bit and for me it works great:

JS:

```
$('body').removeClass().addClass('myCustomClass');
$.blockUI();
```

CSS:

```
div.blockPage{// default layout
width:  30%;
top:    40%;
left:   35%;
text-align:center;
}

body.myCustomClass > div.blockPage{
width: 90%;
left: 5%;
top: 3%; 
text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this maybe an old question but here is the answer for anyone needs it 
http://malsup.com/jquery/block/stylesheet.html 
basicly you will disable the default css by this line
$.blockUI.defaults.css = {};

and then add your css style inside a separate file or so .

Answer (score 1):

You can define a style for your message box outside the javascript and omit the css block. In your case it could be:

```
<style type="text/css">
 div.blockMsg {
  border: '5px solid #F4712';
  backgroundColor: '#6F4712';
  width: '300px'; 
 }
</style>
```

Look at [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/stylesheet.html) (v2) for further infos.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but now days you can use `$.blockUI.defaults.css = {};`  as stated in the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#options)

Comment: So what. This is still style in javascript files. Meaning designers will have to browse through the codebase to find the plugin config. Something otherwise they should never be allowed to modify, and a very important reason to drop this plugin.